# Syntax error near or at v in my SQL query but it doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, asyncpg

Okay, so I'm trying to develop this webhookserver and storing some data.
I tried this but get an ambiguous error?

```sql
INSERT INTO vote_user_data (discord_id, total_votes, points, last_voted)
VALUES(257073333273624576, 2, 150, '2021-04-22')
ON CONFLICT (discord_id)
DO UPDATE SET total_votes = total_votes+2, points = points+150, last_voted = '2021-04-22'
WHERE discord_id=257073333273624576;
```

That didn't work so someone tipsed me about a stackexchange post answering this

I tried that post but that didn't work either.

```sql
INSERT INTO vote_user_data v   (discord_id,total_votes,points,last_voted) 
VALUES(257073333273624576, 2, 150, '2021-04-22') ON CONFLICT (v.discord_id)
DO UPDATE SET v.total_votes = EXCLUDED.total_votes+2,v.points = EXCLUDED.points+150, v.last_voted = '2021-04-22'
WHERE v.discord_id = 2570733332733624576;
```

I do not quite understand what's wrong? It tells me a syntax error near or at "v" in the first line.

Edit: I changed v with table name and now I get a syntax error at second line on `vote_user_data.discord_id)`

```sql
INSERT INTO vote_user_data (discord_id,total_votes,points,last_voted) 
VALUES(257073333273624576, 2, 150, '2021-04-22') ON CONFLICT (vote_user_data.discord_id)
DO UPDATE SET vote_user_data.total_votes = EXCLUDED.total_votes+2,vote_user_data.points = EXCLUDED.points+150, vote_user_data.last_voted = '2021-04-22'
WHERE vote_user_data.discord_id = 2570733332733624576;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your syntax errors:

```
INSERT INTO vote_user_data (discord_id, total_votes, points, last_voted) 
    VALUES (257073333273624576, 2, 150, '2021-04-22')
ON CONFLICT (discord_id) DO UPDATE
    SET total_votes = EXCLUDED.total_votes+2,
        points = EXCLUDED.points + 150,
        last_voted = '2021-04-22'
    WHERE vote_user_data.discord_id = 2570733332733624576;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cafe6b830bf07834b08c211b66a95c0c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: ```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3: ON CONFLICT (vote_user_data.discord_id) DO UPDATE
                                              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 167
```
Nope didn't work, error above^

Comment: @byggmesterPRO . . . I included a db<>fiddle with this exact query (well, I did add newlines for readability but it still works).

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, though the issue wasn't the SQL it was me using a database not supporting the ON CONFLICT function in SQL.